# Override final_price.phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created events observer which is working fine to check whether the customer is logged in or not. If the customer is not logged in then the price will not be displayed.

Here's my code:

`custom_log_out.xml` in

> app/code/Demo/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Demo_Mymodule::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Then created `final_price.phtml` in

> app/code/Demo/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/product/price

which have my custom code:

```
<p>Login to Continue</p>
```

But it's not working can please anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create plugin and use "around" on toHtml function in this class
**Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox**

Create **di.xml** file in your module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="cataloghideprice_finalpricebox" type="{vendor}\{module}\Plugin\FinalPriceBox"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Create this file {vendor}{module}\Plugin\FinalPriceBox.php

```
<?php

namespace {vendor}\{module}\Plugin;


class FinalPriceBox
{
    function aroundToHtml($subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        if($subject->getSaleableItem()->getHidePrice()==1){
            return '';
        }else{
            return $proceed();
        }

    }

}
```

Don't forget to replace {vendor} and {module} with your names.

after that execute those commands

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, actually I am looking to do that using event observer.

Comment: Yes that may work, I tried the event observer  but i had some issues, plugin help me a lot